# Tumblr Embed not working in GitHub Pages

Tags: html, css, embed, tumblr, github-pages

I'm trying to push a website I created off of my personal page and onto a GitHub page.  It is successfully up at https://kalysren.github.io/, but my Tumblr embed isn't showing up.  I've tried it in both Firefox and Chrome with the same results.  If I check its [existing location](http://aestheticstudios.net/), it shows up perfectly in both Firefox and Chrome.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @dundonian, your current problem is mixed content.

As [Github pages is requiring `https` for sites created after June 15, 2016](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/), so you cannot downgrade to `http` and remove mixed content problem. Nevertheless, it's better to serve over `https`.

Trying to get joshwarmuth.tumblr.com served over `https` just by changing url protocol to `https` is not enough because tumblr is redirecting to the `http` version.

[It seems that you can now change this behavior from your tumblr blog settings](https://support.tumblr.com/post/138103206102/ssl-security-which-has-been-available-on-the) and force tumblr to serve over ssl.

Comment: That worked!  You are awesome, @David Jacquel!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your site is https, but the tumblr content is http. You therefore have mixed content, and this is why it's not loading. You need to either, change your gh-pages site to http, or change the tumblr embed to https, assuming that's supported.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I can't find a way to fix that? Is it impossible to host with gh-pages since they use the https while Tumblr uses the http?  Why is it that my current website is http, but can perform the https embeds from ReverbNation and YouTube? I tried simply changing the code to https and that didn't do anything.

Comment: Also, I've noticed that, although the https for tumblr shows up in my code via GitHub Desktop and .com, the change is not showing up when I view the page source? It's committed.  I don't get it?